# Método add: Subir para tabela apenas se já não existir nela

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, try-catch

Olá! Preciso de ajuda para melhorar o método add (via DbContext), por enquanto meu código adiciona independente se já existir na tabela ou não.

Mas como que faz para colocar para adicionar somente se não existir na tabela destino?

Segue explicação do funcionamento atual:

**#1** Seleciono dados de uma tabela x e envio para uma classe auxiliar (csAuxiliar.cs) para armazenar temporariamente.

**#2** Pego os dados dessa classe e envio para uma outra tabela, dentro do banco SQL (TabelaSQL).
Obs: Essa tabela (TabelaSQL) está adicionada no model do projeto (em model1.edmx).

estrutura da **classe auxiliar** de #1:

```
class csAuxiliar
{
    public string infoUM { get; set; }
    public string infoDOIS { get; set; }    
}
```

estrutura da **TabelaSQL** de #2:

duas colunas do tipo varchar: NOME e SOBRENOME.

código:

```
TabelaAuxiliar ta = new csAuxiliar();
TabelaSQL sql = new TabelaSQL();
Banco dbContext = Banco();

(...)
//informações são adicionadas na csAuxiliar
(...)
//informações da classe serão repassadas:

sql.NOME = ta.infoUM;
sql.SOBRENOME = ta.infoDOIS;

try
{
    dbContext.TabelaSQL(sql);
    dbContext.SaveChances();
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
}
(...)
```

No caso ali dentro *try* ele transfere as informações para a tabela no SQL, a minha dúvida é, nessa estrutura de código: Como que eu faço para adicionar uma condicional para adicionar SOMENTE SE JÁ NÃO EXISTIR NA TABELA DESTINO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse é o problema "*insert if not exists*". O problema está no próprio algoritmo. No momento em que você tem duas ações, onde uma depende da outra, você precisa fazer com que os dados usados por ambos não mudem no tempo certo por causa de alguma outra ação feita por outra pessoa. Ou seja, se você executou a primeira ação (SELECT), você realmente precisa ter certeza de que os dados no escopo não mudam antes que você possa fazer a segunda ação (INSERT), caso contrário, o resultado pode estar errado ou inconsistente.

Nesse post tem uma análise profunda desse problema:  [The “insert if not exists” challenge: a solution](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/the-insert-if-not-exists-challenge-a-solution/)

Para o seu caso, estritamente, você poderia colocar uma chave primaria com os campos NOME e SOBRENOME na tabela assim se quando inserir um valor já existente, retornaria um erro que seria capturado pelo bloco `catch()`.

No código, você pode, também, colocar uma ação antes de inserir os dados. **A grosso modo**, ficaria assim:

```
string nome = sql.NOME
string sobreNome = sql.SOBRENOME
var dados = dbContext.SQLTable().Where( s => s.Nome == nome && s.Sobrenome == sobreNome);
if ((dados == null) || (dados.Any())
{
    dbContext.SaveChances();
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, é isso mesmo!